# An error in UrlFetchApp.fetch

Tags: google-apps-script

It becomes connection error when you access to this link.

http://www.yodobashi.com/

Do you know the reason?

```
function myFunction() {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.yodobashi.com/");
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

Comment: My guess is that an admin of that site decided to block the bot used by GAS .